# Strange exception testing EmailSender

Tags: asp.net, testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I have just closely followed all MS instructions on scaffolding the Identity UI in an ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC app. If I run the project, it opens the default home page fine, and links on that page respond well. Yet a simple integration test fails with an exception.

The single method in the `EmailSender` looks like this:

```
public Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
{
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    using (var msg = new MailMessage())
    {
        msg.From = new MailAddress("system@timekeeper.co.za");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("timekeeper@somewhere.com", "something");
        client.Host = "mail.myhost.com";
        client.Port = 25;
        return client.SendMailAsync(msg);
    }
}
```

and my test looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Send_Email()
{
    var sender = new EmailSender();

    await sender.SendEmailAsync("somebody@somewhere.net", "Test Mail", "This is a test");

    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

When I run the test it fails with the following exception:

```
Test method TimeKeeper.Tests.Integration.EmailSEnderTests.Send_Email threw exception: 
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
    at TimeKeeper.Tests.Integration.EmailSEnderTests.Send_Email() in D:\Dev\RestServices\TimeKeeper.Tests.Integration\EmailSEnderTests.cs:line 15
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action action)
```

Comment: When you run it normally do you get the same exception or is it only in the integration test.

Comment: @Nkosi I get the same exception when running it normally, i.e. when I try an register and it tries to send an email.

Comment: `await` the task instead of returning it. Chances are that the client is being disposed before it has a chance to complete sending the email. `await client.SendMailAsync(msg);`

Comment: You should also take note of the warnings in documentation about using the now *obsolete* `SmtpClient` for new development https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks, @Nkosi. I haven't sent mail in a while, so was copying an example (an MS one at that, that doesn't await the task. Makes good sense that it could dispose before completing. Why no make that an answer, very good chance of it being right.

Wow, that's a surprise about `SmtpClient` being deprecated, but they recommend `MailKit`, which I use very often anyway, but only on the message side. Only too happy to use it for everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` the task instead of returning it.

```
public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage) {
    using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    using (var msg = new MailMessage()) {
        msg.From = new MailAddress("system@timekeeper.co.za");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(email));
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("timekeeper@somewhere.com", "something");
        client.Host = "mail.myhost.com";
        client.Port = 25;
        await client.SendMailAsync(msg); //<-- await completion
    }
}
```

Chances are that the `client` is being disposed before it has a chance to complete sending the email.

You should also take note of the warnings in documentation about using the now *obsolete* [`SmtpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) for new development.

> ### DE0005: SmtpClient shouldn't be used
>
> ### Motivation
>
> SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. It is compat-only. It's great for one off emails from tools, but doesn't
> scale to modern requirements of the protocol.
>
> ### Recommendation
>
> Use MailKit or other libraries.

Comment: Thanks, turns out just using MailKit all the way solved all problems. I can't just `await`, because the actual signature of `IMailSender` method doesn't include `async`. It is just `public Task SendEmailAsync`.